# Is it possible to select single matching element in many-to-one

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

I have a class that has an owning class and both of these classes can have versions.

If I update the version of the owning class I don't want to create a new version of the childclass so when I save a new version of the owning-class in the database I want the relation from the subclass to still be valid according to the primary key on the owning-class AND the max version of this "class"

```
public class Child
{
  property Owner Parent { get; set;}
  property int Version { get; set; }   
}

public class Owner 
{
  property Guid Id { get; set; }
  property int Version { get; set; }
  property string Identifier { get; set; }
  property string Namn { get; set; }
}
```

If I now wants to select a Childclass with nhibernate and with that want to automatically select the lastest version of the Parent class which is identified by the Identifier property. This identifier value isn't unique since all versions have the same value. The Id of the Owner class is an Guid for identifing the different version of the same element.

So my question is how can I create this in mapping hbm so that no update needs to be done for an item of Child class when its owner get a new version

In sql this would be something similar to

```
Select * From Child c
Inner Join Owner o on o.Identifier = c.Identifier 
and o.Version = (Select Max(o2.Version) From Owner o2 Where o.Identifier = o2.Identifier)
```

Ask if the question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

The sql provided does imply that there are no foreign keys on database side.

The normal way which has all the properties you want is to split the classes in fixed parts and version parts. No changes for references needed.

Also evaluate if you really need Guid or if an integral type is enough

```
public class Child
{
    property Owner Parent { get; set;}
    property int Version { get; set; }   
}

class Owner
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string NaturalKey { get; protected set; } // never changes
    public virtual Ilist<OwnerData> Data { get; protected set; }

    public virtual BData ActualData { get { return Data.Last(); } }

    public virtual BData GetActualDataToEdit()
    {
        var newData = ActualData.Clone();
        newData.Version++;
        Data.Add(newData);
        return newData;
    }
}

class OwnerData
{
    public virtual int Version { get; protected set; }
    public OwnerData Clone() { ... }
}

// e.g. FluentNHibernate mapping
mapping.List(x => x.Data, p => p.OrderBy("Version"))
```